# Wordpress multilanguage

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I have a Wordpress site that is built on Foundation-theme and using Stella for multilingual plugin. When you change language it works great, but when you click "Home" in the menu, you get redirected to default language.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is always provide code. Well,Check you code either the multilingual is maintaining a `session` in which it stores the current language title like English(en)

OR

check your `URL` may be there is a parameter `?lang=en` so you need to place this parameter on each link on your whole site to keep the user in the respective language.
for Example your logo should be this:

```
<a href="/?lang=en"><img src="/images/logo.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: Im using this now for my logo, <?php bloginfo('url'); ?>. And it works perfect. But when it comes to home button it just goes back to default language. Was hoping someone had been near this problem before ;)

Answer (score 0):

5 Easy Steps To Create A WordPress Multilanguage Website.

Their website. They must also learn to create a WordPress multilanguage website as it will be helpful in reaching new audiences. Creating a multilanguage setup does not require building a new interface. Instead, the content of the existing website is translated into different languages. This helps in communicating the vast majority of the world’s population which is not familiar with English.

Multilanguage interfaces give visitors the convenience of browsing the content in the language of their choice. This sort of personalized user experience helps in fostering strong relationships with customers. WordPress website owners can use the following steps to add multilingual capabilities to their interface.
Read More:-[WordPress Multilanguage Website](https://supdrew.com/5-easy-steps-to-create-a-wordpress-multilanguage-website/)