# website in multiple language versions based on cookie

Tags: wordpress, http, web, multilingual

I need to make a web site that can switch between multiple language versions.

my Idea is to maintain two language versions of the web site and switch between them based on cookie. hence the domain and all URLs remains same. Is it good idea or there any better solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the good idea try this useful [multilingual pluggin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/).

After Installation:
May be you got this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425145/wordpress-multilanguage/17425282#17425282) so I have provided a detailed answer too.